# Find slope of parametric equation

Tags: calculus

I am looking for the slope of the parametric equation:

$$x=e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}$$
$$y=e^{3t}+5e^{-3t}$$

Find slope when $t=2$.

As of now I have figured the slope of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be:

$$\frac{e^{12}-5}{e^{12}-2}$$

at $t=2$ however I think I went about this problem the wrong way. To explain how I came to that slope is I calculated the derivative of y over the derivative of x and simplified.

Could someone tell me if I went about this the wrong way?

EDIT: Also I don't know if this is relevant to the problem, but I found a point at:

($e^6-2e^{-6}$ , $e^6-5e^{-6}$) at t=2.

Comment: You did great, but I think there is a sign error in the denominator ($+2$).

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah I just rechecked my work and saw I switched it out of the blue for some reason. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Now, $\displaystyle y=e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}\implies \frac{dy}{dt}=3e^{3t}-2\cdot(-3e^{-3t})=3(e^{3t}+2e^{-3t})$

Similarly, find $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}$

Finally divide and put $t=2$

Comment: Thanks, this should help me along the right path.

Comment: @BobDunakey, my pleasure. This is a valid way for parametric equations

Comment: My only other question just to make sure I am doing it correctly as I am fairly new to parametric equations is that I just need to divide and nothing fancy with derivatives right?

Comment: @BobDunakey, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule